# Code from Angular Service is not reachable

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, local-storage

I´m using Local Storage (https://github.com/cyrilletuzi/angular-async-local-storage) in a Angular 5 Service. First I want to load the data from storage. If the value does not exist, I want to load data from firebase. But if I check if data exists the database request is not reachable from service... I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`.

PS: The value "user" definitely does not exists in this example.

**That´s what I tried**

```
getDbFromUser(uid) {

    this.localStorage.getItem('user').subscribe((data) => {
      if (data) {
        console.log(data);
      } else {
        console.log('Nothing found');
        // Load data from Firebase
        this.dataObjRef = this.afDatabase.object(`data/users/${uid}`);
        this.data = this.dataObjRef.valueChanges();
        return this.data;
      }
    }, () => {
    })
  }
```

Comment: this: `this.localStorage.getItem('user')` does not returns an observable!

Comment: But I return an Observable if user does not exists...

Comment: And if it exists then you return what??:>

Comment: Nothing yet :-)

Comment: So you got undefined error. Problem solved.

Comment: `if(this.localStorage.getItem('user')){
// user is available in the LS
}else{
return observable
}`

Comment: But the item definitely NOT exists...so it should be called the Observable...

Comment: Well, its not..

Comment: as far as I know localstorage gettem does not return observable. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem

Comment: I´m using the following async local-storage: https://github.com/cyrilletuzi/angular-async-local-storage

Comment: You could put that info right away as my magic crystal ball does not work nowdays.

Comment: I edited my post with this info few minutes after creating it...

Answer (score 2):

Check [this demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v3wfcl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

You must be doing something wrong, Play around by commenting:

```
this.localStorage.setItem('user', user).subscribe(() => { });
```

once the value is set and then reload the page with commented line.

In case, this doesn't help, feel free to **fork** it and replicate the scenario and let me know

Comment: `preview-ee4d58d6ef0576b4e139b.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of null` (https://angular-qlhtg7.stackblitz.io)

Comment: @eleinad : My bad. It wasn't working because I did a typo as `let user: { firstName: 'Henri', lastName: 'Bergson' };`  where it should be `let user = { firstName: 'Henri', lastName: 'Bergson' };` .

Comment: @eleinad can you please confirm and mark it as an answer so that it can be helpful to others as well

Answer (score 1):

localStorage.getItem function just returns a value and not an observable. It's actually pretty straight forward.

```js
var user = localStorage.getItem('user');
if(typeof user === 'undefined') {
   // do you firebase syncing here.
}
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` ...:/

Comment: `if (typeof user != observable) ` would work...it is correctly too? :-)

Comment: You can't subscribe to localStorage.getItem, it returns a string.

Comment: typeof user != observable, won't work too because again it returns string. ``localStorage`` isn't a database, it's more like an object variable but stored in chrome.

Comment: I´m using the following async local-storage plugin: https://github.com/cyrilletuzi/angular-async-local-storage

Comment: Ohh now i get it. I thought you we're using the native localStorage. Does it have a module? If it does import it into AppModule. If not add this service in your AppModule providers

Comment: It was set already as module... so, the problem is not the storage plugin...the plugins does it right and returns null, because the item `user` really does not exist. So the `else` part is important...seems that this not fires and I have no access to this Observable..